# Django - "check_token" always returns TRUE

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When a user registers on my app, an account verification link is sent to his email. When clicking on the link the first time, everything is fine and the account is verified, but when clicking on the same link again, the validation goes through, whereas it should raise an "authentication failed" error, since the "check_token" should return false, right?

Here's the verification serializer:

```
class VerifyAccountSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uid = serializers.CharField(min_length=1, write_only=True)
    token = serializers.CharField(min_length=1, write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ['uid', 'token']
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        uid = attrs.get('uid')
        token = attrs.get('token')

        uidb64 = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uid))
        user = UserAccount.objects.get(pk=uidb64)

        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid account. Please contant support')

        if not PasswordResetTokenGenerator().check_token(user, token):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Account verify link is invalid. Please contant support.')

        user.is_guest = False
        user.save()

        return user
```

And the view function:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def verify_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        serializer = VerifyAccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data

            data['user'] = UserSerializer(user).data
            data['token'] = AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]

            # delete previous token
            tokens = AuthToken.objects.filter(user=user.id)
            if len(tokens) > 1:
                tokens[0].delete()

            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

It's kinda weird why it's not raising an error, because, in my other serializer for resetting the password via a link as well, I have the exact same thing going on, except there's one more extra field for the password, and if click on that link for the second time, I get a validation error.

Comment: Hard to answer this question without seeing what `check_token` is doing

Comment: check_token is Django's build-in function, which comes from "django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator"

Comment: Ah cool didn't know that thanks

Comment: Looking at the [`source`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L35) it seems the token can be valid for up to `settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` seconds which is by [`default 3 days`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout)

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that I have the same validation setup in "SetNewPasswordSerializer", and there if use the link for resetting the password twice, I get a validation error.